# GAE ndb filter by key(id)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I want to filter by Key value( If I can, by Id)

Developers console offers searching data with key value.

I want to do in my code just like:

```
DataModel.query(DataModel.key > ndb.Key('DataModel', id_value)).order(
                DataModel.date,
                DataModel.times).fetch(2000)
```

Which raise error...

my id_value is integers.

How can I search and filter to get data that have higher id than id_value?

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The filtering by inequality on key is fine, what's wrong is that you **cannot** combine filtering by inequality on one thing, with ordering by **another** thing.  To quote https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries under **Limitations:** ...:

> combining too many filters, using inequalities for multiple
>   properties, or combining an inequality with a sort order on a
>   different property are all currently disallowed.

The last one of these three limitations is what you're running into.

Comment: i'm not sure that this is true actually; I'm trying to run a query using .filter(Entity.key > ndb.Key('Entity', key_id)), and am getting "Incomplete key found for reference property \__key__"

Answer (score -1):

One option is to fetch all the results from the query and then sort them in your program (instead of in the `.order()` clause).

A second option is to query on all three fields () to reduce the number of results, and then sort them as above:

```
DataModel.query(DataModel.key > ndb.Key('DataModel', id_value),
            DataModel.date > some_date,
            DataModel.times > some_times)
```

A third option is to use [MapReduce](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/1-MapReduce) to process large quantities of data.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this does not actually work? See my comment on @Alex Martelli's post